# How to hide edit/create button based on group in Odoo?

Tags: button, permissions, odoo-9, odoo

If we keep `edit="false"` and `create="false"` then we can remove the edit and create button. But is it possible to remove these buttons bases on groups?. That is for admin it should be visible and for user it shouldn't be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Security in Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/security.html)

> **Access Control**
>
> Managed by the `ir.model.access records`, defines access to a whole
>   model.
>
> Each access control has a model to which it grants permissions, the
>   permissions it grants and optionally a group.
>
> Access controls are additive, for a given model a user has access all
>   permissions granted to any of its groups: if the user belongs to one
>   group which allows writing and another which allows deleting, they can
>   both write and delete.
>
> If no group is specified, the access control applies to all users,
>   otherwise it only applies to the members of the given group.
>
> Available permissions are creation (`perm_create`), searching and
>   reading (`perm_read`), updating existing records (`perm_write`) and
>   deleting existing records (`perm_unlink`)

So you need to create a file with the model permissions  (`module_name/security/ir.model.access.csv`) in order to get what you want.

The content of this file should be something like this:

[image]

By the way, if you want to make something only visible for the administrator then you should add this attribute to the element: `groups="base.group_no_one"`

Comment: Hi is it possible if the visibility of Edit/Create buttons is based on the workflow states? Can you give also an example? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure, that's even easier. You must use the `attrs` or the `states` attributes. `attrs="{'invisible': [('state','=', 'draft')]}"`, `states="draft,proforma2"`

Comment: But next time you should ask a different question, don't ask new things in a comment. If not the community is going to get angry with you :)

Comment: Hi I already try that but not working, 
you can reply to my existing question by visiting this link : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071622/how-to-hide-or-disable-edit-button-in-odoo-9

Comment: Ahh! OK I misunderstood your question. I'm afraid the only way is to do it in Javascript. If I have time I can answer you with the solution or some approach